# Obtain the index of an element in a multidimensional array containing other elements with same values and use that to populate a form?

Tags: php

I have this table (picture below) that contain answers to questions, the fields in the table include AID, Answer, QuestionNumber and IsCorrect, the is correct has 0s for wrong options and 1 for correct option. now I have made a form to enable the admin edit the questions and answers, one question at a time (picture below). I have selected the question from the question table and answer from the answers table. But i am having the following challenges

1. I want to get the number of the correct option (option 1, 2,3 or 4) that is the correct option so i can populate the correct choice field in the form but all my effort using array search to determine the position of IsCorrect with a value of 1 failed.
2. how do i construct my logic such that the right rows in the answer table are updated when i finish editing and save since each option has its own QID and I dont know how to take that along to the edit form and hold them such that each ID points to the appropriate option?

This is part of my code.

```
if ($job == 'get_question'){

// Get question
if ($id == ''){
  $result  = 'error';
  $message = 'id missing';
} else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `QID` = '" . sanitize((int)$id) . "'";
  $query = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$query){
    $result  = 'error';
    $message = 'query error';
  } else {
    $result  = 'success';
    $message = 'query success';
    while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $mysql_data[] = array(
        "QuestionCategory"          => $test['QuestionCategory'],
        "Question"                  => $test['Question'],
        "QuestionNumber"            => $test['QuestionNumber']
      );
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `QuestionNumber` =" . $test['QuestionNumber']);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($q)){

    /*I have tried many things without success, this is just one of them to give you a clue to what my plight is, and this is just for problem #1 */

        foreach($rows as $key => $value){
            $index = array_search(1, $rows);
            if($value == 1){$mysql_data['IdsCorrect'] = array_search($key, $rows); }

            }
                }


    }
  }
}
```

[Answers Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQZnQ.jpg)
[Edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRRyi.jpg)

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Okay, Thanks, i have used PDO in some projects before but really did not understand it very well. i will adopt mysqli because it has similar structure as mysql

Comment: Yes but don't just use `mysqli_` as a swap out, switch to using prepared statements too :) otherwise there's no point at all

Comment: Ok, i really appreciate